# SQLite query to perform search and multiple filters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, cordova, cross-platform

I have a set of data (table) as shown below.

```
+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
|  Name   | Surname | Country |  Status   |
+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
| Ryan    | Gosling | U.S.A.  | Citizen   |
| Raymond | Green   | Germany | Citizen   |
| Andrew  | Hollow  | U.S.A.  | Immigrant |
| Sam     | Giggs   | U.S.A.  | Citizen   |
+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
```

A user can perform following tasks,

1. Search (name or surname) no filters (country and status)
2. Search (name or surname) + one or both the filters (country and status)
3. No search (name or surname) but one or both the filters (country and status)

### What queries should I write to solve this issue?

Edit:
As Rob has refused to do my homework , let me explain what I have done! It's not ethical but manages to work.

If a user searches through the table using name or surname as a keyword I bring those results using an OR query. And then run that result through the selected filter arrays (if any) in a for loop and show the final result by removing duplicate entries.
If there is no search performed and just a set of filters applied then I bring entire table and run through for loop as described above.
In case only search is performed then I bring the strip down result using OR query as said above.

Comment: NO; I will not do your homework :P

Comment: Lol, I am not asking you to do my homework!

Comment: I tired and failed...I have managed to find a workaround but it's not good enough. I want an sql query..

Comment: @Rob Brander, check edited portion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're approaching this the wrong way, there is no filter or search in sqlite, you have the `WHERE` clause and some logical operators, you can combine those to do what you want. Here is an example for 2:

```
SELECT * FROM [tableName] WHERE (Name = "something" OR Surname = "somethingElse") AND (Country = "someContry" OR Status = "someStatus");
```

You just need to figure out the logic, the important part is to delimit each part using parenthesis.

Comment: I tried this approach. But my problem is user can select multiple filters within the same column. Like Country='U.S.A.", "U.K.". And I am not getting how to write a query for this case.

Comment: @aB9 Just add more `OR` conditions. Eg: `((Country = "U.S.A" OR Country = "U.K" OR Country = "someContry") OR Status = "someStatus")`. You can also use the `IN` condition. Eg: `Country IN ("U.S.A", "U.K", "someContry")`

Comment: Ohk, so I need to run a for loop to form a query based on the number of filters used, right?

Comment: @aB9 Yes, that should work but creating a SQL statement using string concatenation is unsecure. You should sanitise the user input. Usually that is done by using a prepared statement (depends on programming language).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! I tried using OR conditions and now it is working. :)